# How can I make a bullet point appear in a label?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to create a label with a bullet point. Here is what I tried but it doesn't seem to work at all:

```
<Label Text="\u2022 Hello" />
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try

```
<Label Text="&#x2022; Hello" />
```